# TinyMCE 4 keeps removing background-size

Tags: html, css, tinymce

TinyMCE removes `background-size` property from inline style.

I've tried:

1. `<div style="background: url(img_url_here) no-repeat center;background-size: cover;">`
2. `<div style="background: url(img_url_here) no-repeat center / cover;">`

Part of the config (without menus and other non relevant stuff):

```
default_config = {
    statusbar: false,
    relative_urls : false,
    convert_urls: false,
    entity_encoding: "raw",
    extended_valid_elements : "em[class|name|id]",
    valid_children : "+*[*]",
    valid_elements:"*[*]",
};
```

I've also tried using `valid_styles` without success, then it would remove all styles, e.g.:

`valid_styles:"*[*]"`

`valid_styles:"+[*]"`

I found both usages on Google. It is possible to set one by one, but I want to allow all styles:
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-filtering/#valid_styles

Maybe it is possible to remove style "checking", because, e.g. if I enter some style incorrectly, it will get auto removed. Maybe TinyMCE doesn't recognize `background-size` and treats as invalid.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I can't try it without a code, but maybe you use valid_styles in wrong way. Documentation says about using an object notation (object:{ }):

```
valid_styles: { //<- object opener
'*': 'example1', //<- styles that can be use for all selectors comma separated
'div': 'example2' //<- styles that can be use for this selector comma separated
} // <-object closer
```

not property (property: value) notation. Can you try this?

```
default_config = {
statusbar: false,
...
extended_valid_elements : "em[class|name|id]",
// I will delete valid_children and valid_elements
valid_styles: {
'*': 'background-size'
}
//don't use comma in last element 
};
```

Comment: Still removes it, and removes all other styles as well. We tried to make it work for editor/article writer, who writes product descriptions, but we suggested using .css file and classes, more proper way of doing it anyway than inline styles. Also it will be easier to edit all at once later if needed. It does not solve the initial question here on stackoverflow, but I couldn't find solution. We are using PrestaShop 1.6. with its default tinymce in the Back Office.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've concentrat on the middle part of the text. The `valid_styles: {' * ': 'background-size'}` will force TinyMCE to remove all styles on all elements that aren't background-size. So it works, but not this way you want it.
I found [somewhere](https://community.tinymce.com/communityQuestion?id=90661000000MrVKAA0) a "configuration hack" to insert style as attribute option and bypass styles checking. I wonder, if it will help you?

Comment: I try to do small test, on fiddle TinyMCE don't remove background-size: cover property. But don't display div, when you don't set height. [Test here](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/rygaab)